# A student to be an English teacher should study hard

Tags: infinitives

A: A student to be an English teacher should study hard.

B: A student, to be an English teacher, should study hard.

I think A and B are correct. Do you have any different ideas?

Comment: It doesn't matter, since both are awkwardly phrased. You would do well to recast the sentence entirely.

Comment: They mean different things.

Comment: Grammatical, but not totally acceptable according to Orwell's Sixth Rule (_Don't sound unnatural {without a good reason}_). Might work in a period novel (Victorian, say). But then, as Greybeard says, you need to be aware of the potential ambiguity. // In modern English, for sense (B), front the to-clause. 'A student to be an English teacher' doesn't work in modern English; we use 'student teacher'.

Comment: @Greybeard, Could explain what the different thing is?

Comment: (A) would probably be salvaged as 'A student teacher aiming at becoming an English teacher should study hard'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sentences don't sound like native English, and they're actually kind of confusing. You're better off with something like:

> To become an English teacher, a student should study hard.

That still sounds a little weird, but at least it's not confusing.

Something more native-sounding would be like:

> If a student wants to become an English teacher, she should study
> hard.